# Archived macOS app launches with blank window

Tags: xcode, macos, wkwebview, archive

I have a macOS app with a ViewController that renames and resizes the app window, has several buttons, and a WKWebView that loads a default webpage on launch.

The project itself is an .xcworkspace file, since it includes the CocoaPod SwiftSoup for HTML scraping.

The app runs great in the simulator.  When it launches, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to run this app on my Mac outside of Xcode.  I am not planning on releasing it to the App Store, it is just for my personal use.

I archive the project with Products > Archive, then select "Distribute App", then  "Copy App" to create a directory with the archived app.  This all works great.

When I launch the app, I just get an incorrectly sized blank title-less window, without the buttons or WKWebView from my Storyboard:

[image]

The app isn't hanging. I can open the "About" menu item, etc., so I know the app is running.  it just doesn't seem to be using my Storyboard to draw the UI.

What would cause an archived app to differ from the app running in the simulator?

The funny thing is that I WAS able to archive this same app back in November under High Sierra, so I'm guessing the issue is either Cocoa Pods and/or Mojave related.

My debugging leads me to suspect either CocoaPods or Mojave related

My debug:
1) While debugging, I restored a version of the project from November.  When I archive that restored project, I get the same blank non running app.

2) I AM able to archive another brand new project that doesn't use Cocoa Pods, so my guess is that this is either CocoaPods and/or Mojave related issue...

Any suggestions on how to proceed debugging, or help resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

I am using Xcode 10.2.1 under Mojave 10.14.5.

Comment: Duplicate of [Macos app displays view in Xcode, but is totally blank when launched outside of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550970/macos-app-displays-view-in-xcode-but-is-totally-blank-when-launched-outside-of)

Comment: @Willeke Agreed. I am marking the answer below as correct because IWECon points to an Apple Developer post that provided code examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macos app displays view in Xcode, but is totally blank when launched outside of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550970/macos-app-displays-view-in-xcode-but-is-totally-blank-when-launched-outside-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by WKWebView.
So, you need remove WKWebView from IB and then create it with code and add it to the view.

REFER:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116047
http://www.openradar.me/23699297

Comment: Why do you feel WKWebView is the problem? Is this a new issue with Mojave? Previously, I was able to release a version of this code with WKWebView in IB in High Sierra.  Can you point me to a description of the issue in Apple docs? I can't find any references to this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Macos app displays view in Xcode, but is totally blank when launched outside of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572593/4244136)

Comment: @SDGray I can't find any issue about the problem. I just remove WKWebview from IB then it is running normally with Mojava. My project is older and can be run normally on High Sierra, so I think it is a WKWebView problem that can't load the other view.

Comment: @SDGary I find it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116047  ,  http://www.openradar.me/23699297

Comment: @IWECon  Excellent! The Apple Developer Form link you shared provided me with simple coding examples.  Thanks!

Comment: @IWECon  I am marking your answer as correct.  May I ask you to edit your answer above to include the Apple Developer link directly in the answer, so future searches will find it wihtout having to read all the comments?  Thanks again.

Comment: @SDGray sure~ :)